# _construct in C, a macro used in an oop project

Tags: c, oop, constructor, macros

Recently, I start to learn  object-oriented programming by using C.
I found some interesting material on the web. One of those is QMonkey/OOC-Design-Pattern repository on Github.
https://github.com/QMonkey/OOC-Design-Pattern

Here is my question :

Below is the base.h included in QMonkey/OOC-Design-Pattern.
This is the base macro used in this OOP C project.
I found many explanations about #,##,offsetof,and container_of.
The only thing I can't figure it out is the usage of _destruct and _construct.Where may I find their explanation?

Thanks for any help.

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// clang-format off
#define container_of(ptr, type, member)                 \
    ({                              \
        const typeof(((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); \
        (type *)((char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member));   \
    })

#define new(TYPE, args...) TYPE ## _construct(malloc(sizeof(TYPE)), ## args)
#define delete(TYPE, ptr)   do              \
                {               \
                    TYPE ## _destruct(ptr); \
                    free(ptr);      \
                }               \
                while(0)
// clang-format on

#endif
```

Comment: Makes me wonder of how the author of that project defines OOP... `new` and `delete` has absolutely zero to do with OOP. Also, any C code that attempts allocation/deallocation of classes without using opaque/incomplete type is probably of rather questionable quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_construct` and `_destruct` are just suffixes that are appended to the class name using the [token pasting operator, `##`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html). So if `TYPE` is `MyClass` then there will be constructor/destructor functions called `MyClass_construct` and `MyClass_destruct`.